# jQuery to get value embedded in the outer value attribute

Tags: jquery, html

Appreciate for the help in parsing and getting the value of a hidden input which is embedded within another value attribute of another hidden input.

The generated HTML is as follow:

```
<td headers="COMMENT">
  <input type="text" name="f12" size="60" maxlength="2000" value="Archived" id="f12_0001">
  <input type="hidden" name="f01" value="<input type=&quot;hidden&quot; name=&quot;f13&quot; value=&quot;LOCAL&quot;  />" class="rowHandle" id="f01_0001">
</td>
```

What is the jQuery for getting the "LOCAL" value in the sample code above?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : Here I am reading value of first hidden input and then value of jQuery object of first hidden input which gives second hidden input value.

```
$(function(){
   var innerHiddenValue = $($('input[name="f01"]').val()).val();
   alert(innerHiddenValue );
});
```

Working [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NLT8p/329/)

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why you are doing this, but the code is as follows:

```
var val = $("#f01_0001").val(); //get value of outer element
var $val = $(val); //make a jquery object using the value string
alert($val.val()); //get the value of the hidden element
```

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/YXaTD/)

Comment: Correct answer! Sorry I can only vote 1 correct answer. The code is generated by Oracle APEX. Thanks

Comment: No problem! I know I am a few seconds late